# Page transitions with Firebase Auth

Tags: kotlin, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I provide user login with Firebase Auth in my application that I developed with Jetpack Compose in Android Studio (Google and Phone Number). I want the user to be redirected to OnBoardScreen if they are logging in for the first time, if the user already has an id in Firebase, I want them to be redirected to HomeScreen. However, after being redirected to OnBoardScreen on their first login, I want them to switch to a DataEntryScreen. How can I do this?

If first user -> OnBoardScreen - LoginScreen - DataEntryScreen - HomeScreen

If an existing user (not logged out) -> HomeScreen

If an existing user (logged out) -> LoginScreen - HomeScreen

In my experiments, I cannot provide both conditions for page transition (I can only provide a condition between OnBoard and HomeScreen, but I cannot add the DataEntryScreen condition for the first user).

Comment: What have you tried so far in code? Please edit your question and add the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: Since you tagged the question with `Kotlin`, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).